# Is it a good habit to print the bool value from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def f():
    return True

print(f())
```

or

```
def f():
    return True

if f():
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Should I round it in if statement or simply print out the value, in Python 3.3.2?

Answer (score 3):

`print` automatically converts input to its string representation.  So, the two methods actually do the exact same thing.  Considering that, why not use the first?  It is a lot cleaner.

Also, the second method can really be simplified:

```
print('True' if f() else 'False')
```

Having that much code for something so simple isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If your function always returns a `bool`, then just print it, like this:

```
print(f())
```

If you need to convert it to a string without printing it, use `str(f())` or `repr(f())`. For the `bool` type these two are equivalent, but e.g. if their argument is an `str`, they are different: `repr(str_obj)` returns it properly quoted and escaped.

If it's not always a `bool`, but you want to print something depending on its truth value, then use an `if`, like in your question or in iCodez' answer. Alternatively, you can convert it to a bool, and then print it:

```
print(bool(f()))
```

Comment: I agree with @LorenzoDonati. This is not written as a factual answer, but as your opinion. You should say something like "Python booleans implement `__repr__` and `__str__` to print their truth value, so that `print(f())` is actually equivalent to the snippet you posted, but more concise. Python encourages this concise style, so the first form is absolutely ok."

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on my answer, I've expanded it to be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the:

```
print(f())
```

form looks nicer. However, one thing to consider is that you have baked in a call to print what is essentially debugging output with the call that is causing the functionality to be invoked. This would make it painful later when you want to turn off all the annoying `print` statements when you are ready to build upon your program.

You could instead have a function such as:

```
LOGGING_ENABLED = True

def print_if(my_bool):
    if LOGGING_ENABLED:
        print str(my_bool)
```

This will ensure that the function is always invoked but the debug output happens only if you want it.